# Lightbox without rel tag or addRel without jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox, rel

This is the idea. I want to put a lightbox (or slimbox or mediabox or whateverbox) on my forum so that it will open user-posted links in lightbox.

Problem is, lightbox requires the `rel=lightbox` tag, and people are too lazy to use the custom bbcode that adds the correct rel tag to the link.

So, can lightbox (or any other) work for all links without the rel tag?

The alternative is to add the `rel` tag to all links.
I can use the 'addRel' function from jquery, but it would be a waste to include the whole of jquery only for this one function.

How can I add a rel tag without jquery?

Comment: do you want to get all a tags and add rel="lightbox" or is there something that differentiates them from normal a's, like a class etc?

Comment: a little progress. i know it need getElementsByTagName and setAttribute.

just dont know how to make it works.

Comment: this question evolved into: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576283/help-with-getelementsbytagname-setattribute-and-regex-javascript> :)