# getElementsByTagName setAttribute and regex javascript

Tags: regex, lightbox, setattribute, rel

i want to put rel=lightbox to some links that mediabox support using javascript.

i try this and wonder why it's not working?

test: http://jsbin.com/opica

please help edit this: http://jsbin.com/opica/edit

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("a");
var regexku=/^.+(((twit)|(tweet)|(com/video.+)|(flickr.com.+)|(tube.com.+))|((gif)|(jpe?g)|(png)|(flv)|(swf)|(mp3)|(mp4))$)/;

for(i=0;i<x.length;i++)
 {
a=x[i].getAttribute('href');
if (a.match(regexku) != null)
   {
   x.item(i).setAttribute("rel","lightbox");
   }
 }

</script>
```

Comment: What is xmlDoc in this context? You didn't meant document, right?

Comment: actually, the original problem is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575451/lightbox-without-rel-tag-or-addrel-without-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you open the Error Console (Tools -> Error Console in Firefox), you'll see two errors on your page:

```
Error: xmlDoc is not defined
Source File: http://jsbin.com/opica
Line: 35

Error: invalid regular expression flag v
Source File: http://jsbin.com/opica
Line: 21, Column: 38
Source Code:
var regexku=/^.+(((twit)|(tweet)|(com/video.+)|(flickr.com.+)|(tube.com.+))|((gif)|(jpe?g)|(png)|(flv)|(swf)|(mp3)|(mp4))$)/;
```

The later is fixed by escaping the slash as Bart suggested (`com\/video`).

The former says there's no such thing as `xmlDoc`. You probably meant the page's document, in which case you should replace it with `document`.

Next the whole thing probably won't work because you should run the script after the page is finished loading. In jQuery it's `$(document).ready(function() { /* do your work here */ })`, google how to do it using the whatever framework you're using (mootools-yui?).

After that as you can see, the rel attribute is set on the links: http://jsbin.com/elaca/edit. The fact that the whatever library you're using still doesn't work means you're using it wrong. You didn't even link to the page you've downloaded the library from so that someone could look up the documentation for you...

Comment: tnx for the tips.
i'm no programmer. so most of that i just copy paste without fully understanding it.
i just learn all these few hours ago.

mediabox: http://mediabox.googlecode.com http://iaian7.com/webcode/mediaboxAdvanced
and google hosted mootols: http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/documentation/index.html#mootools

it works if i manually put in the rel tag. but i want to use js to put the rel tag

Comment: No putting rel="" manually doesn't work: click nature1.jpg here http://jsbin.com/ihoji/edit . First try editing this to make it work without setting the attribute dynamically. Then you can update the commented-out code to set the correct attribute dynamically. Like I said it does what you wanted it to - sets rel="lightbox" on <a> elements.

Comment: while problem not (yet) solved, this very question is resolved. thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping the `/` between `com` and `video`.

Comment: @DennyHalim, okay, but when you escape the `/`, the regex becomes a valid one. If the regex `doesn't work`, you might try to explain what strings you're trying to match. because `doesn't work` does not tell me much.

Comment: i dont know much about regex. but i tested the regex here http://www.regextester.com/ and no error.

Comment: @DennyHalim, yes, like I said: your regex matches all the strings from your tests ('.jpg', '.gif' , '.png', '.flv', '.swf' and 'youtube.com/watch'). So the regex is correct.